# How should a talis godol be folded?

Tags: halacha, tallit-gadol

The first fold of a talis godol can be either along the blue or red line in the picture below.

[image]

Is there any preference as to how to fold it according to the sources?

Comment: I've not seen this discussed anywhere, but, the end product customarily would is a long-and-thin fold with all 4 tzitzit together, so as to enable one to throw it over one's shoulder to check the validity of the fringes,